# Where to poll sensor data in ViewModel environment?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, sensormanager

I like to get sensor data (eg. gyroscope) from a fragment using mvvm. So far I got it working but only in a fragment, completely working around the mvvm environment. It doesn't work from the viewmodel file. How can I stream sensor data into LiveData?

This is working code, but bypassing viewmodel:

```
class RPMFragment : Fragment(), SensorEventListener {
private lateinit var rpmViewModel: RPMViewModel
private lateinit var sensorManager: SensorManager
private lateinit var gyroscope: Sensor


override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    rpmViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(RPMViewModel::class.java)
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rpm, container, false)
    val textView: TextView = text_rpm

    rpmViewModel.text.observe(this, Observer {
        textView.text = it
    })

    this.sensorManager = activity!!.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
    sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE)?.let {
        this.gyroscope = it
    }

    return root
}

override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
    if (event?.sensor?.type == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
        text_rpm.text = "z axis: " + event.values[2].toString()
    }
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, this.gyroscope, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    // repeat that line for each sensor you want to monitor
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor?, accuracy: Int) {

}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can write custom [`LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData) class to do the "heavy lifting" and let your ViewModel just be a simple host:

```
// viewmodel only serves as a host for livedata
class RPMViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    val rpmLiveData = RPMLiveData()

    // inner class just to have access to application
    inner class RPMLiveData : LiveData<String>(), SensorEventListener {
        private val sensorManager
            get() = getApplication<Application>().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager

        override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor, accuracy: Int) {
            //unused
        }

        override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent) {
            postValue("z axis: ${event.values[2]}")
        }

        override fun onActive() {
            sensorManager.let { sm ->
                sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE).let {
                    sm.registerListener(this, it, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onInactive() {
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(this)
        }
    }
}
```

With this ViewModel in place your fragment is now lightweight and only reacts to changes from `LiveData`:

```
class RPMFragment : Fragment() {
    private val rpmViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(RPMViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rpm, container, false)
        rpmViewModel.rpmLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            text_rpm.text = it
        })
        return root
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! @Pawel: Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your ViewModel extend AndroidViewModel to get access to the current Context. Then let your ViewModel implement the SensorEventListener Interface to get informed about sensor events. Post the event data to your LiveData:

```
class RpmViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application), SensorEventListener {

    private lateinit var sensorManager: SensorManager
    private lateinit var gyroscope: Sensor
    val sensorDataLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun registerSensors() {
        sensorManager = getApplication<Hero2Application>().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE)?.let {
            this.gyroscope = it
        }

        sensorManager.registerListener(this, this.gyroscope, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    fun unregisterSensors() {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this)
    }

    override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
        if (event?.sensor?.type == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
            sensorDataLiveData.postValue("z axis: " + event.values[2].toString())
        }
    }

    override fun onAccuracyChanged(p0: Sensor?, p1: Int) {

    }
}
```

In your Fragment you could then listen to the Event like this:

```
viewModel.sensorDataLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
        Log.d("RPMFragment", it)
    })
```

Register and unregister like you did before:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    viewModel.registerSensors()
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    viewModel.unregisterSensors()
}
```

Comment: I think the answer from @Pavel is a bit more elegant!